# Approximating the Characteristic Function of a Cantor Type Set with Continuous Functions in Stromberg's Book

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, cantor-set

On page $276$ of his book Stromberg mentions that $\xi_{P}$ (where $P\subset[0,1]$ is a Cantor type set)  can be written as the pointwise limit of a sequence of contiuous functions on $[0,1]$.

He then suggests the following sequence: $f_n=1$ on $P$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $\text{dist}(x,P)\geq 1/n$.

I assume he means $f_n(x)=1$ if $\text{dist}(x,P)< 1/n$. But then $f_n$ is not continuous at $x$ if $\text{dist}(x,P)=1/n$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Presumably, if $0 < \operatorname{dist}(x,P) < 1/n$, the function interpolates linearly between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: So the proposed $f_n$ is not continuous right? Would something like $f_n(x)=1-n \text{dist}(x,P)$  if $0\leq\text{dist}(x,P)\leq1/n$ do the job?

Comment: The function you describe in your question is not *defined* on the set $\{ x : d(x,p) \in (0,1/n)\}$.  Presumably, the intention is to define it on this set so that it is continuous.  If you make the assumption you made then, yes, the function is not continuous.  Why would you make that assumption?

Comment: I really wish it was defined, but Stromberg don't mention anything about the definition of the function on $(0,1/n)$. Your assumption make more sense.

Comment: I can't see the full context, but he *is* defining the important features of the functions:  they are $1$ on the Cantor set, and $0$ on increasingly large subsets of the complement of the Cantor set.  In the places where the function is not defined, a precise definition is inessential; one just has to come up with a way of filling in the gaps so that the resulting functions have the desired properties.  A linear interpolation works if you want continuity, however we could also fill in the gap with something that makes each approximating function **smooth** if we so desired.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I only need continuity. So if I use my previous suggestion I believe we have $f_n$ continuous on $[0,1]$ for each $n$ and $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Am I right?

Comment: That's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the primary difficulty here is that the author has elided some details.  The author wants to approximate the characteristic function of a Cantor set by a sequence of continuous functions, $f_n$.  He gives us the *important* properties of the function, but skips the details:  namely,

- $f_n(x) = 1$ if $x \in P$ (where $P$ denotes the Cantor set being considered),
- $f_n(x) = 0$ if $d(x,P) > 1/n$ (where $d(x,P) = \inf\{ d(x,y) \mid y\in P\}$ is the distance from $x$ to $P$; pardon the overloading of notation), and
- $f_n$ is continuous.

It is evident that if such a sequence of functions exists, then it converges pointwise to $\chi_P$ (the characteristic function of $P$):

- If $x \in P$ then $f_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$.  Thus for $x \in P$, $f_n(x) \to 1 = \chi_P(x)$.
- If $x \ne P$ then (because $P$ is closed) $d(x,P) > 0$, which means that there is some $N$ so large that $n > N$ implies that $d(x,P) > 1/n$.  Hence $f_n(x) = 0$ for all such $n$.  Thus for $x \not\in P$, $f_n(x) \to 0 = \chi_P(x)$.

The only trick is to ensure that each $f_n$ is continuous.  There are a lot of ways that this can be done.  An "obvious" technique is to use linear interpolation:  define $f_n(x) = 1-n d(x,P)$ for any $x$ such that $0 < d(x,P) < 1/n$.  It is also possible to build the $f_n$ so that they are smooth (the usual technique would be to convolve $\chi_P$ with a smooth bump function supported on a ball of radius $1/n$, or something like that).

The point is that these functions do not need to be given precisely—it is sufficient to know that there exist functions which get the job done.  Because an exact pointwise definition is inessential (and, frankly, is likely to bog the exposition down in irrelevant detail), the author has chosen to omit such definitions.  This is pretty standard practice in mathematical writing:  leave out the bits that you expect an informed reader to fill in on their own.  It is then up to the reader to fill in the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope to be an informed reader next time!

Comment: In this case "informed" means not only that you understand the underlying mathematics, but also that that you know how to read a mathematical document.  This is a skill which takes time to learn (and probably needs to be taught).  I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the trouble, you could define $f_n(x) = (1-d(x,P))^n.$

Comment: Right! This function is smooth and since $0\leq\text{dist}(x,P)<1$ (with $\text{dist}(x,P)=0$ iff $x\in P$) we have $f_n \to \xi_{P}$ pointwise. But I believe that defining $f_n(x)=1-n \text{dist}(x,P)$ if $0<\text{dist}(x,P)<1/n$ also works.